Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration at hibernatTest.Main.main(Main.java:10)
`i am trying to implement Non-maven project using Hibernate but i keep facing this error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
at hibernatTest.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
... 1 more
[and this is a screenshot of the project strcture](https://i.sstatic.net/4Bknu.png)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
